# Install subset of packages listed in a requirements.txt file with PIP

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

I'm wondering if it's possible to install a subset of the packages listed in a requirements file using the PIP CLI command or do I have to wrangle stuff in a makefile to get something like this?

```
pip install -r [package1, package2] requirements.txt
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it would do exactly what you have in mind, but you could try something like:

`python -m pip install Something Another --constraint requirements.txt`

See [*pip*' documentation section on *constraints files*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files).

Comment: Ah that's a cool feature didn't knew it existed thanks!